# Printer Driver for HP Color LaserJet CP1217

Tags: macos, drivers, printer, hp-laserjet

I have problems with my printer. Because I have used Windows, I bought me the HP LaserJet CP1217, a few years ago. But now I bought me a MacBook Pro. I have experienced just that there are no Mac drivers available for this printer. I google this problem several times, but there are no solution. Perhaps somebody in this forum can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Gutenprint](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/MacOSX.php) project.

Gutenprint provides excellent drivers for many printers that are otherwise unsupported on Mac OS X.

For the this particular HP printer, however, perhaps this article may help:

[Getting an HP Color LaserJet CP1215 working on a Mac](http://ryan.bigwoofs.com/2008/12/getting-an-hp-color-laserjet-cp1215-working-on-a-mac/)

Comment: Gutenprint unfortunaly don't support the HP LaserJet CP 1217.

Comment: @alschbpk see edit to my answer. It looks rather involved, but may help.

Comment: I don't know why, but this is the solution. It works. Thanks a lot.